# Git Commit Daily or Commit when Feature is completed?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push

I want to know what will be more feasible (or convention to follow) if i Commit/Push my daily progress on a feature or i Commit/Push when a feature or a module is completed ?

Comment: define "completed"

Comment: lets say that you are working on a feature and suddenly your hard disk is corrupted, what will be the best solution for this scenario?. The point is Git is a source control so use it, it doesnt matter if you commit it daily in a feature branch. if you are worried about the number of commits you can always squash that

Comment: .....daily.....

Comment: @BryanOfEarth: means .. lets Say i am working on hero area. (lets just assume) and i takes more then a day. should i commit daily even after i added a block of that hero module and complete means if i am done with hero area its responsivness and all stuff.

Comment: @karthick:  That is something i didnt think of. But i am using SSD's still god forbid if ever happend. i am worried about hundreds of commits. 
to me commit is to obviously recording every change, but more of Source Control : means , you can revert your program back to its working state if something ever happend. version controlling , source controlling. 
it is really hard a point where to revert in 100+ commits

Comment: A common work flow is to fork the repo, commit often, and maybe used rebase to combine certain commits, push your work regularly to your own repos. And as soon as the branch is ready to be merged back to development/testing or how ever you call the branch that is used before merged to master or stable do a pull request from your repos to the main repos.

Comment: @t.niese: i see. that means commits are only for us. to see the record or history of our project?
I am working on my own project right now. Working solo.On previous project i've done daily commits or can say i commit when ever i do something with my project, and when i completed my project i came to know that i had total of 385 commits on a small-medium .net project.

Comment: While developing a feature branch like `feature/hero_area` you ideally do a commit for each logical part you changed. Before you push you could (if necessary)  stash multiple related commits into one, reorder commits and change the commit messages. And before you merge your feature branch to your development branch you could rework the commit history even further, so even if you do hundreds of commit while working on the feature you will end up in a few commits in the end when you do the merging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "Commit" in this context.  For many historical / non-git users, the notion of a "commit" was to commit changes back to the definitive central repository (from which all other users pull updates).

So, do you mean a git "commit" to your local repo, or a git "push" to the remote repo?

If it's a local repo "commit" then do that all the time. And do it at the end of the day if it's not frowned upon. that way you can keep track of changes.

A "push" to the remote repo (to the associated feature branch, of course) is a different beast.

Much of this depends on how you and your team organize your work / work day.  Some teams require the checkin (commit / push) so that you don't lose your work. Some are fine with "just commit locally, and push when it works".

It also depends on your team's branching strategy.  Much of the time you may be the only person working on a feature. That means you're the only one in a branch.  If you check in non-working code then it MIGHT not be an issue.

If you have multiple committers to a branch, then your broken code will stop their work when it comes time for them to commit.

If you have a process where all branches are CI builds then that means bad builds up on the CI board. You may not want that.

I am a fan of both pushing working code AND not losing my work. Here is my approach

- Do your work in small chunks (blah blah Agile blah - not talking about that).  Fix one part of what you're working on.  If that works "ok" (doesn't blow out a tire) then commit the changes. IF your team is good with it then PUSH this work to the branch in the remote repo.
- coordinate with your team, or watch the CI build of your branch to ensure the integrated code passes tests. If it's all good then keep going. If not then go back and fix your work until your branch is Green.

Comment: Yes.  that is what i am saying , after intializing , git already is tracking every change you made, so why to commit on every little chunk of code you write.
i do push when i am done with that module i am working on. 
it is realy complex and hectic to find a commit or reverting your code back to working state if you make some mistake and commit that way back in the list of 100s of commits.

Comment: @ArslanAmeer Git is not tracking every change you make automatically. It shows only the difference between the last commit, and the staged and unstaged changes. So if you add lines of code and remove those same lines later without doing a stage or commit in between then this lines are lost. You stage and commit so that you not accidentally loose changes you already did, you push after each  day you worked that code so that you have a backup (or to allow others to see the progress) and you merge when the feature is finished.

Comment: @t.niese hmm i was saying the same, or trying to say so. got it. I never had an idea of Squash before. i think Squashing multiple commits (commits you do daily) before you push repo, is convenient.